# Android Language Translation Error

Tags: android, language-translation

I am Developing an Android Application, by default it is running in English properly then i Translate it in to Welsh and Urdu by translate String file into corresponding language and placed it into values-cy and values-ur.When i run it show error message like 
' **02-09 05:07:35.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(584): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #11:**' 
You must supply a layout_width attribute..I studied that particular xml but it didn't noticed any problem in that line but it worked in engish properly(I used Styles/String and Theme in my resource).After that i create a new xml file with only one Textview here i gave all styles within that Tag..
.Now i locked with this problem.So please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: looks like one of your layout files is missing layout_width. Use lint utility to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using custom theme. If so,call styles from theme. May be it will work.

Try it.. Happy coding :)